# Sci-fi book in which people can photosynthesize with their hair

Tags: story-identification, books

I am searching for the name of a sci-fi book in which people can photosynthesize with their hair, and because of that, the rich cut their own hair and food is very expensive.

The story is about a family who have lost their daughter during a ski trip, in the fictional future Iran.

It came out between 2005 - 2015.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe this is *[By Light Alone](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9281340-by-light-alone) (2011)* by Adam Roberts.

Synopsis from Goodreads:

> **In a world where we have been genetically engineered so that we can photosynthesise sunlight with our hair** hunger is a thing of the past, food an indulgence. The poor grow their hair, **the rich affect baldness and flaunt their wealth by still eating**. But other hungers remain...
>
> **The young daughter of an affluent New York family is kidnapped**. The ransom demands are refused. Years later a young women arrives at the family home claiming to be their long lost daughter. She has changed so much, she has lived on light, can anyone be sure that she has come home? Adam Roberts' new novel is yet another amazing melding of startling ideas and beautiful prose. Set in a New York of the future it nevertheless has echoes of a Fitzgeraldesque affluence and art-deco style. It charts his further progress as one of the most important writers of his generation.

And [this review](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2011/sep/06/light-alone-adam-roberts-review) from The Guardian mentions that the story begins at a ski resort on Mount Ararat:

> It's about a hundred years in the future. The poor are living on sunlight, which they absorb through their hair. A woman can't sustain pregnancy on this miserable diet, so there's a big shift: the masses are chronically short of children; and that's going to be important. **The story itself begins at a ski resort on Mount Ararat**. Three couples, holiday acquaintances, parade their callous affluence. They are proudly bald and mountainously fat; they have disgusting table manners and engage in joyless, thunder-thighed illicit sex. They are nasty to the local staff, and ignore their own small children, whose "carers" must produce these trophy objects for a few minutes' display, before quickly removing them again. **Then Leah, the older child of the central couple, George and Marie, disappears. The regional police take a relaxed view; they explain that child kidnap is commonplace**, then arrest the "carer". The motive is not ransom, the girl will not be returned: and that's the end of that.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 5):

*By Light Alone* by Adam Roberts.

> In a world where we have been genetically engineered so that we can photosynthesise sunlight with our hair hunger is a thing of the past, food an indulgence. The poor grow their hair, the rich affect baldness and flaunt their wealth by still eating. But other hungers remain...

Summary from [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9281340-by-light-alone) above. It also mentions the kidnapped daughter.